# Pannable canvas effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

It's more of a question really, but I don't know where to start with this one at all. I'm working on a site at the moment and we've cited the following sites as reference:

http://exhibitions.guggenheim.org/storylines/ 
http://www.apple.com/uk/start-something-new/

As you can see, both have the same effect and allow you to pan the 'canvas' within the viewport. I've search high and low but can't find any documentation or plugins for such a thing. The closest I found but it still doesn't allow you to pan with `mouseMove` is this: http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/#/home

Like I say though, it's still quite far away from what I'm trying to achieve. Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions or plugins people might know of would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pan canvas with mouse**

You can pan the canvas with the `ctx.translate(x,y)` function, but this function is relative and can be tricky to use if you do not understand matrix math. Or with `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y)` where the last two numbers set the origin location on the canvas. This function is absolute so you do not need to track the current transformation matrix. The origin is the where coordinates 0,0 are.

**Using setTransform**

So if you set the the origin to

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2)
```

and then draw a circle at 0,0

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0,0,100,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
```

it will appear in the center of the canvas as that is where the new origin is.

**Implementing**

Now all you need is to use the mouse to pan.

First create var to track the origin location

```
var originX = 0;  // default to the top left of the canvas.
var originY = 0;
```

Depending on how you render the following will flag when to update the canvas transform

```
var panOnMouse = true;  // if you are using requestAnimationFrame 
                        // or another realtime rendering method this should
                        // be false
```

Then create a helper function to set the origin

```
function setCanvasOrigin(ctx){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,originX,originY);
}
```

**The mouse**

Now the mouse event listener and tracking the mouse movements First a object to hold mouse information.

```
var mouse = {
    x : 0,  // holds the current mouse location
    y : 0,
    lastX : null,  // holds the previous mouse location for use when mouse down
    lastY : null,  // as this is unknown start with null
    buttonDown : false, // true if mouse button down;
    panButtonID : 1,  // the id of the pan button 1 left 2 middle 3 right
}
```

Then create an event listener to get the `mousemove`, `mousedown`, and `mouseup`

```
function mouseEvent(event){
    if(buttonDown){  // if mouse button is down save the last mouse pos;
        mouse.lastX = mouse.x;
        mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
    }
    mouse.x = event.offsetX; 
    mouse.y = event.offsetY;
    if (mouse.x === undefined) {  // for browsers that do not support offset
       mouse.x = event.clientX; 
       mouse.y = event.clientY; 
    }
    // now handle the mouse down 
    if (event.type === "mousedown" && event.which === mouse.panButtonID ) {
        mouse.buttonDown = true; // flag the pan button is down;
        mouse.lastX = mouse.x;   // set the last pos to current
        mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
    } 

    // now do the pan is the mouse is down
    //
    if(mouse.buttonDown){
        originX += mouse.x - mouse.lastX; // add the mouse movement to origin
        originY += mouse.y - mouse.lastY;
        if(panOnMouse ){
            setCanvasOrigin(ctx);
        }
    }
    // handle the mouse up only for the pan button
    if (event.type === "mouseup" && event.which === mouse.panButtonID) { 
        mouse.buttonDown = false;
    } 
}
```

If you have `panOnMouse` as false then call `setCanvasOrigin` at the start of your main render loop.

All that is needed now is to add the mouse event listener to the canvas.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",mouseEvent);
```

**Last notes**

So now when the user clicks and drags with the correct mouse button the canvas origin will be dragged to where ever it is wanted. It can even be off screen. Just draw everything as you normally did.

To reset the pan just set the origin to zero

```
originX = 0;  // default to the top left of the canvas.
originY = 0;
setCanvasOrigin(ctx);  // set the transform
```

Because the origin has moved the mouse position on the canvas does not match the panned canvas coordinates. To get the position of the mouse over the panned canvas just subtract the origin from the mouse. You can add it to the end of the mouse event function

```
mouse.realX = mouse.x - originX;  // get the mouse position relative to the
mouse.realY = mouse.y - originY;  // panned origin
```

If the user moves off the canvas while panning you may lose the mouse up event and have the button stuck down. You can listen to `mouseout` and `mouseover` events to control what happen in those situations.

And that is how to pan the canvas with the mouse.